# Online C project for excercising?

Tags: c, git, open-source, project

Recently I'm back into (embedded) C programming because of a new job.

I never had a vast amount of C experience in my career and in the recent years (lacking in C) even that little amount dropped a little further. Thats too bad.

So, in order to improve my C skills and to speed up my learning process I thought I could make some extra C excercises at home. First I wanted to find some kind of "excercise book" online that would be fun to solve. (This also might be a solution.) But then this came to my mind: isn't out there somewhere a project which is

- online
- organized and supervised/controlled
- under version control, possibly git
- open and recommendable to individuals even on unprofessional C level?

I imagine myself here as some kind of volunteer who, while contributing to the project, would also learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't meet all of your suggested requirements, but the problems in [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) are challenging yet fun to solve. I've approached it specifically from the angle of parallel computing, but the problems are generic enough that you can exercise plenty of other aspects in software engineering.

Comment: Once you solve a problem, you gain access to the corresponding forum where previous solvers share their code. An amazing experience in humility.